# Check if Folder exists and delete it in Azure Data factory (ADF)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've a simple task to check if a specific folder exists in OnPrem server and delete it if exists. I have tried several combination with 'Validation' Activity but all the times it is giving Timeout (even if the folder exists). I'm sure ADF has access to that folder as it is the same ADF pipeline that at one time in the execution creates that folder.
Any suggestions on what I'm missing?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Timeout:**  Specifies the timeout for the activity to run. If no value is specified, default value is 7 days ("7.00:00:00"). Format is d.hh:mm:ss

Screenshot provided in question suggests **timeout value is 1 second**. Which is too small.

Increase value of timeout and then check.

[image]

Refer - [Validation activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-validation-activity#type-properties)

Comment: Hi @AbhishekKhandave-MT , Thanks for looking into this. I'm sure I have tried different timings but no luck. What makes me wonder is, why it requires a time out at all when the Folder is already present. I agree that is require in case if some body want to keep looking for the folder/file. But in my case at least the folder is present and I just want to ensure it is not deleted by some one.