# Azure Data Factory: How to check if a folder exists

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I've setup a Cost Management export that is trigged weekly to a Storage Account.

In that storage account the CSV is exported inside a container, a folder, another folder, and then inside a folder with `FROM-TO` dates:

[image]

I would like Data Factory to check:

- If a folder exists --> do something
- If a folder exists but has the suffix "*-imported" --> do nothing

So I need a boolean.

So I created a Validation but the only thing I can can put is a binary:

[image]

I don't need a binary or a CSV or whatever other file format.

How to check if a folder exists and if it has or not a suffix?

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002270/check-if-folder-exists-and-delete-it-in-azure-data-factory-adf) is not helping.

Answer (score 2):

You do need a Dataset, and Binary makes the most sense for this scenario.

Create a Binary Dataset with a folder path parameter:

[image]

Reference the parameters in the Connection tab:

[image]

In the Pipeline, use GetMetadata. Point to this Dataset and select "Exists" under "Field list":

[image]

If you do not include "-imported" in the folder path, those will be ignored.

Here is a link to an article I wrote about using [GetMetadata](https://causewaysolutions.com/blog/introduction-to-get-metadata-in-azure-data-factory/) and another about [Parameterized Datasets](https://causewaysolutions.com/blog/creating-reusable-datasets-in-azure-data-factory-with-parameters/), you may find them useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two validation activities. First activity is to check if the folder `fromdate-todate-imported` exists. If it exists, do nothing. If first validation activity gets **failed**, add another validation activity to check if folder `fromdate-todate` exists. If exists, Do the required activities.

[image]

- In validation1, Binary dataset is taken, and file path is given as `containername/folder1/folder2/fromdate-todate-imported`. Filename is left blank in the file path.
- In validation2, Binary dataset is taken, and file path is given as `containername/folder1/folder2/fromdate-todate`. Filename is left blank in the file path.

I run pipeline for three different cases.

**case:1 Folder exists and folder name contains -imported**

[image]

- When pipeline is executed, it is run succesfully. Only validation1 has run.
  [image]

**Case:2 When folder exists and folder name does not contain -imported**

[image]

- When pipeline is run, all 3 activities are executed.
  [image]

**Case:3 When folder doesn't exist**
Results when pipeline is run,
[image]